# Send file to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I Have a request in web form code behind and i like call web api send Object with a property of type IFormCollection, the object properties sending but file not

```
WebRequest wrqst = WebRequest.Create(URLService + method);
var postData = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string key in form.Keys)
                {
                    postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(form[key]));
                }

                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

                wrqst.Method = "POST";
                wrqst.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wrqst.ContentLength = data.Length;

                using (var stream = wrqst.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                
                WebResponse oResponse = wrqst.GetResponse();
```

I Receive file in Request.File
How i can send File?

Answer (score 0):

To send a file in your web API request, you need to use the multipart/form-data content type instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/WEB/Pos_PropertyImageSave")]
    [Route("api/POS/Pos_PropertyImageSave")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Pos_PropertyImageSave()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            bool IsUpload= false;

            /******************Image Upload*********************/
            if (request.Files["PropertyImage"] != null )
            {
                obj.AttachemntName = request.Form["AttachemntName"] != null ? request.Form["AttachemntName"].ToString() : "";
                obj.AttachemntNo = request.Form["AttachemntNo"] != null ? request.Form["AttachemntNo"].ToString() : "";
                HttpPostedFile uploadImage = request.Files["PropertyImage"];
                if (uploadImage.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    //Convert the File data to Byte Array which will be store in database
                    byte[] bytes;
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                    {
                        bytes = br.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
                    }

                    filesInfo file = new filesInfo
                    {
                        File_Name = Path.GetFileName(uploadImage.FileName),
                        File_Type = uploadImage.ContentType,
                        File_Data = bytes

                    };
                    string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + Path.GetFileName(uploadImage.FileName);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, bytes);
                    obj.AttachemntType = Path.GetExtension(uploadImage.FileName);
                    obj.AttachemntImagePath = "../Upload/" + Path.GetFileName(uploadImage.FileName); ;
                    obj.AttachemntImage = file.File_Data;
                    // obj.AttachemntName = Convert.ToBase64String(file.File_Data, 0, file.File_Data.Length);


                }
                  IsUpload= true;
                /*******************End Of Image Upload*************/


            }


            

            if (IsUpload)
            {
                String sMessage = string.Format("Image has been " + obj.Mode + " successufully.");
                Response responseclass = new Response(sMessage, sMessage, ((int)HttpStatusCode.OK), true);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<Response>(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseclass);
                return response;
            }

            else 
            {

                Response responseclass = new Response("", "Image Upload Failed", ((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent), true);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<Response>(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseclass);
                return response;
            }
             

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            FailureResponse responseclass1 = new FailureResponse(ex.Message.ToString(), ((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest), false);
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = Request.CreateResponse<FailureResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseclass1);

            throw new HttpResponseException(response1);
        }
    }

   public class filesInfo
    {
        public string File_Name { get; set; }
        public string File_Type { get; set; }
        public byte[] File_Data { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).